# How to get process ID of a specific process using wmic and check on error?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created a batch script which runs WMIC to get the PID from a specific process. If I open the bat script I see 'ProcessID 1234' or 'No Instance(s) Available.' in the command window.

I want to create an IF statement where I check if the output from this command was an PID or `No Instance(s) Available.`. Which variable can I use for this?

**My code:**

```
wmic process where "Name like '%%cmd.exe%%' and CommandLine like '%%WatchdogStarter.bat%%'" get processid
if %%outputfromthiswmiccommand%% == 'No Instance(s) Available.' ....
```

Comment: I suggest looking into the findstr command and Errorlevel

Comment: can you share more code? More probably it is related to [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266)

Comment: I added my code. I'd like to know how i can read the output from the wmic command to use it in the if-statement.

Comment: Another alternative (if you have access to the watchdog script) is to have the script in question maintain a text file with its own pid in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys.
I solved my problem by using `TASKLIST` instead of `WMIC`.

`WMIC` gave me the output, starting with 2 non-ascii characters, and 2 lines of not usable information. I had to filter these, what worked.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in ('wmic process where name^="chrome.exe" get Processid') do echo %%i
```

This worked more or less, but when the program I tried to 'watch' wasn't running it gave me a random pid, I think the pid I got was from the `WMIC` process that was looking up the requested process id.

That's why I tried to use `TASKLIST` and search the full output with `FINDSTR` to find the correct pid I was looking for. This worked for me.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%P in ('tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "WatchdogStarterBATCH"') do set pid=%%~P
```

Thanks for all the help!:)

Answer (score 6):

You could use following batch code to get either the process identifier value or the error message assigned to variable `ProcessID`.

```
@echo off
set "ProcessID="
for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%I in (`wmic process where "Name like '%%cmd.exe%%' and CommandLine like '%%WatchdogStarter.bat%%'" get processid 2^>nul`) do set "ProcessID=%%I"
if "%ProcessID%" == "" (
    echo PID could not be determined.
) else (
    echo PID is: %ProcessID%
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`

See also [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) to understand `2>nul` which redirects error message `No Instance(s) Available.` (English Windows) written to **STDERR** to device **NUL**. The angle bracket in `2>nul` must be escaped with `^` to apply `2>nul` to command **wmic** instead of command **FOR**.

Redirecting error message to device **NUL** and making sure `ProcessID` does not exist if **wmic** command was not successful is better than comparing output of **wmic** with a specific string as the error message depends on language of Windows. This solution is independent on language of Windows.

Comment: ++ Language-neutral: ignoring this makes scripts very fragile over the course of time

Answer (score 1):

I also think you are having issues with the quotes (or double quotes as in my example): e.g. I have following piece of code in my scripts:

```
IF "%5"==""
```

You see that there are (double) quotes at both sides of the '==' sign.

In other words, I would replace your line by:

```
if '%%outputfromthiswmiccommand%%' == 'No Instance(s) Available.' ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If wmic fails to find the PID %errorlevel% will be set. Use that in the IF statement.